# When I attack a village why do barbarians appear to attack my troops?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I'm fairly new at Clash of Clans. I noticed sometimes when I attack a village all of a sudden fairies or barbarians come out and attack my troops. How do I know when this is going to happen and how do I protect my troops? Also how do I use that myself and defend my village with them? I assume it has something to do with requesting reinforcements from a clan.

Comment: Lol.. "fairies". There's no such thing in this game.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are assuming right. Here is how it works:

Clan troops can be requested once you join a clan. Those troops will then move from the donor's camps to the requestor's clan castle. The maximum number of troops that can be received by the requestor is limited to the requestor's clan castle capacity.

Those troops can be used in attacks, or if kept in the castle, will defend the requestor's base whenever enemy troops enter the clan castle's range.

Once a clan castle troop is out, it will usually go to attack the earliest troop that was put down by the attacker until it is down and only then go to the next troop(s).

To get rid of them, the two most common strategies usually start with placing 1 barbarian within reach of a clan castle and out of reach of defenses to test if there are troops inside (no, you can never know for sure whether a clan castle has troops or not unless you scout first, which is possible in revenge raids or clan wars) and place more barbarians one at a time until all castle troops are out.

What follows is then:

- Place more barbarians one at a time at the edge of the base to drag out the castle troops and bunch them up, then surround them with barbarians and archers.
- Bunch them up by placing barbarians one at a time and zap them out with a lightning spell (those can be unlocked at town hall 5 after building a spell factory).

Usually though, the best defensive units are those that hit both ground and aerial units. This is because you might be faced with balloons for example, that Barbarians and Giants cannot hurt at all.

So the best units are the likes of Archers, Wizards and Dragons which are elixir troops and for later Dark Elixir troops, Minions, Witches, Lava Hounds.

After the type of attack, the type of damage helps too, and splash damage is usually better. One particularity of Witches is that they additionally generate more troops (Skeletons, that however hit only ground troops) that can greatly stall an attacker.

Comment: So if you have troops in your clan, they will automatically protect you next time you're village if attacked, you don't need to do anything?

Comment: @Celeritas In your clan castle, yes. I forgot to mention that they will not defend again if they die, but if they survive, they will be able to defend again (Clan Castle is usually shortened to 'CC', so troops in there will be called CC troops).

Comment: Ok thanks. You say to bunch up castle troops using barbarians and archers. I've never seen any of my troops actually attack them. Will they, or are you just saying using them to physically get in the way?

Comment: @Celeritas Your units will usually attack the closest things to them, so they will indeed attack the defending units if they are close. Your units will even sometimes stop attacking the building they were hitting to attack the CC troops, but remember that Giants and Goblins won't attack the CC troops unless all defenses (Giants) or all resource structures (Goblins) are down. Maybe a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s2Mbb3C5Yfs) can help? I can't watch videos right now, so I hope that's the right one ^^;

Comment: you diden't mention that only 5 troops can be donated per player, so to fil a level 1 clan castle you will need 2 players to donate to your clan castle.

Comment: @codermaster I didn't mention that because you can re-request if needed, 20 minutes after the first request to continue filling your castle. And next, that's not entirely true. It depends on the troop size. For example, I can give 5 wizards (each of size 4) to a lv 3 clan castle (which has a capacity of 20) and fill it up completely.

Comment: yes but that are stil 5 troops I ment with barbarians because he is still not that advanced so he will not yet find troops that are more than one spot in the castle (except gigants maybe)

Comment: @codermaster That doesn't change the fact that you don't need 2 players. Request, and request again after the countdown is over to fill your castle regardless of the troop being donated to receive troops from the same player.

Comment: two players would be easyer though and request after request every 20 minutes got me banned several times :(

Comment: @codermaster Huh, that's unfair, unless your received troops exceed your donations.

Comment: i know, many clans don't like people that request a lot

Comment: @codermaster Maybe you need a different clan. In any case, requesting more than donating is frowned upon.

Comment: yeah thats why its better to get from multiple players

Comment: @codermaster Uh.. sorry? Having more received troops does not depend on the number of players, only donating, and even there, it's better for the player donating...

Answer (score 0):

the barbs that were attacking your troops (as you said) just came out from the persons clan castle. To defend your troops from those barbs I think tou should use giants as a meat shield because they have a lot of health.

Answer (score -1):

The clan castle can hold 10 troops at level 1, 15 at level 2, 20 at level 3, 25 at level 4, and so on. At level two, a person can get a healer or "fairy.” Usually, if you want to know if they have clan troops, there is no way to tell in a normal battle, but you can guess by looking at the base. If their base has a bunch of debris and tombstones and their gold mines and elixir collectors are full, they probably don't have troops in their clan castle since they’re inactive. Also, if they aren't in a clan, then they probably don't have clan troops.